# How to intelligently change branches in subversion?

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm out of the office working on a large codebase and the time has come to change branches.

I cannot checkout the whole project from scratch because my connection is flaky,
the vpn client is even flakier, and together they cannot handle the larger commits.

Since the branches are very similar, I should be able to ask subversion to transform
*this* branch into *that* branch by pulling down only the differences.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Svn switch command?

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html

Comment: Oh, +1 btw. Was going to post that exact same link.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I was under the impression that switch was for updating your URL when you move the repository. Great.